Patch method gives back "acknowledged": false in Postman
I want to update a product in my PATCH request. I get back "acknowledged": false on my request in Postman. I tried to use $set but I get the same result acknowledged: false from postman.
What dose acknowledged: false mean and how can I fix this problem?
My POST, GET, and DELETE request's is working but PATCH is a problem
I get back status code 200
Here is my model and patch request:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("product", productSchema);

const express = require("express");
// Setting up router
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Product = require("../models/product");

// URL`s here will be forwarded to app.js through URL /products
router.get("/", (request, response, next) => {
    Product.find()
        .exec()
        .then((document) => {
            console.log(document);
            // You could make a check to send back not found, but here you have actually found the list except you have no products
            // You will get back an empty array
            // if() {
            response.status(200).json(document);

            // } else {
            //      response.status(404).json({
            //            message: "No enteries found"
            //      });
            // };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({
                error: err,
            });
        });
});

router.post("/", (request, response, next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: request.body.name,
        price: request.body.price,
    });
    product
        .save()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            response.status(201).json({
                message: "Handeling POST requests to /products",
                createdProduct: result,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({
                error: err,
            });
        });
});

router.get("/:productId", (request, response, next) => {
    const id = request.params.productId;
    Product.findById(id)
        .exec()
        .then((document) => {
            console.log("From database:", document);
            if (document) {
                response.status(200).json(document);
            } else {
                response.status(404).json({
                    message: "No valid entry found for provided ID",
                });
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({ error: err });
        });
});

router.patch("/:productId", (request, response, next) => {
    const id = request.params.productId;
    const updateOps = {};
    for (const ops of request.body) {
        updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
    }
    Product.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: { updateOps } })
        .exec()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            response.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({
                error: err,
            });
        });
});

router.delete("/:productId", (request, response, next) => {
    const id = request.params.productId;
    Product.deleteOne({ _id: id })
        .exec()
        .then((result) => {
            response.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({
                error: err,
            });
        });
});

module.exports = router;


I was expecting my product to be updated.
